# Inconsistent Eq and Ord instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a large Haskell program which is running dismayingly slow.  Profiling and testing has revealed that a large fraction of the time is spend comparing equality and ordering of a particular large datatype that is very important.  Equality is a useful operation (this is state-space search, and graph search is much preferable to tree search), but I only need an Ord instance for this class in order to use Maps.  So what I want to do is say

```
instance Eq BigThing where
(==) b b' = name b == name b' &&
            firstPart b == firstPart b' &&
            secondPart b == secondPart b' &&
            {- ...and so on... -}

instance Ord BigThing where
compare b b' = compare (name b) (name b')
```

But since the names may not always be different for different objects, this risks the curious case where two BigThings may be inequal according to ==, but comparing them yields EQ.

Is this going to cause problems with Haskell libraries?  Is there another way I could satisfy the requirement for a detailed equality operation but a cheap ordering?

Comment: I've done it, but have to be careful what libraries you use.

Comment: Do you need to order according to `name`, or is any kind of consistent ordering acceptable, just so that you can use `Map`s and it's fast?

Comment: Any ordering is acceptable.

Comment: If you need comparison on all fields, an interesting technique that I've seen once or twice is to compute a hash and include it in the data structure, then compare on the hash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, using `Text` or `ByteString` instead of `String` could help *a lot* without changing anything else.

Generally I wouldn't recommend creating an instance of `Eq` inconsistent with `Ord`. Libraries can rightfully depend on it, and you never know what kind of strange problems it can cause. (For example, are you *sure* that `Map` doesn't use the relationship between `Eq` and `Ord`?)

---

If you don't need the `Eq` instance at all, you can simply define

```
instance Eq BigThing where
    x == y  =  compare x y == EQ
```

Then equality will be consistent with comparison. There is no requirement that equal values must have all fields equal.

---

If you need an `Eq` instance that compares all fields, then you can stay consistent by wrapping `BigThing` into a `newtype`, define the above `Eq` and `Ord` for it, and use it in your algorithm whenever you need ordering according to `name`:

```
newtype BigThing' a b c = BigThing' (BigThing a b c)
instance Eq BigThing' where
    x == y  =  compare x y == EQ
instance Ord BigThing' where
    compare (BigThing b) (BigThing b') = compare (name b) (name b')
```

---

**Update:** Since you say any ordering is acceptable, you can use hashing to your advantage. For this, you can use the [hashable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashable/1.2.0.10/doc/html/Data-Hashable.html) package. The idea is that you pre-compute hash values on data creation and use them when comparing values. If two values are different, it's almost sure that their hashes will differ and you the compare only their hashes (two integers), nothing more. It could look like this:

```
module BigThing
    ( BigThing()
    , bigThing
    , btHash, btName, btSurname
    )
where

import Data.Hashable

data BigThing = BigThing { btHash :: Int,
                           btName :: String,
                           btSurname :: String } -- etc
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
-- Since the derived Eq/Ord instances compare fields lexicographically and
-- btHash is the first, they'll compare the hash first and continue with the
-- other fields only if the hashes are equal.
-- See http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html#sect10.1
--
-- Alternativelly, you can create similar Eq/Ord instances yourself, if for any
-- reason you don't want the hash to be the first field.

-- A smart constructor for creating instances. Your module will not export the
-- BigThing constructor, it will export this function instead:
bigThing :: String -> String -> BigThing
bigThing nm snm = BigThing (hash (nm, snm)) nm snm
```

Note that with this solution, the ordering will be seemingly random with no apparent relation to the fields.

You can also combine this solution with the previous ones. Or, you can create a small module for wrapping any type with its precomputed hash (wrapped values must have `Eq` instances consistent with their `Hashable` instances).

```
module HashOrd
    ( Hashed()
    , getHashed
    , hashedHash
    )
where

import Data.Hashable

data Hashed a = Hashed { hashedHash :: Int, getHashed :: a }
  deriving (Ord, Eq, Show, Read, Bounded)

hashed :: (Hashable a) => a -> Hashed a
hashed x = Hashed (hash x) x

instance Hashable a => Hashable (Hashed a) where
    hashWithSalt salt (Hashed _ x) = hashWithSalt salt x
```