# Haskell: do standard libraries assume Eq and Ord are compatible?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is a followup question to [Inconsistent Eq and Ord instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114899/inconsistent-eq-and-ord-instances).

The question there is essentially: when declaring `Eq` and `Ord` instances for a type, must one ensure that `compare x y` returns `EQ` if and only if `x == y` returns `True`?  Is it dangerous to create instances that break this assumption?  It seems like a natural law one might assume, but it doesn’t appear to be explicitly stated in the Prelude, unlike e.g. the monad or functor laws.

The basic response was: it is a bit dangerous to do this, since libraries may assume that this law holds.

My question, now, is: **do any of the standard libraries (in particular, `Set` or `Map`) make this assumption?  Is it dangerous to have a type with incompatible `Eq` and `Ord`, so long as I am only relying on the standard libraries supplied with GHC?**  (If big-list questions were still acceptable, I would be asking: which commonly used libraries assume this law?)

**Edit.** My use-case is similar to that of the original question.  I have a type with a custom instance of `Eq`, that I use quite a bit.  The only reason I want `Ord` is so that I can use it as the domain of a `Map`; I don’t care about the specific order, and will never use it explicitly in code.  So if I can use the derived instance of `Ord`, then my life will be easier and my code clearer.

Comment: "which commonly used libraries assume this law" --- people's brains?

Comment: Indeed, a better question would be for a (non contrieved) example where `(a == b) /= (compare a b == EQ)` would make any sense.

Comment: Is this just idle curiosity, or do you have a use case in mind where you think it makes sense to make the two differ?  If the latter, I would love to see it presented (seriously, I am curious now, and can't think of a good use case myself....)

Comment: @jamshidh: edited to describe my use-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `Ord` itself in the [standard prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) requires there already be an `Eq` instance:

```
class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where
    ...
```

So it would be just as wrong to violate

```
    x == y           =  compare x y == EQ
    x /= y           =  compare x y /= EQ
```

As it would be to violate (from the default definitions for these operators in Ord).

```
    x <= y           =  compare x y /= GT
    x <  y           =  compare x y == LT
    x >= y           =  compare x y /= LT
    x >  y           =  compare x y == GT
```

**Edit: Use in libraries**

I would be quite surprised if standard libraries didn't make use of `Ord`'s `==` and `/=` operators. The specific purpose operators (`==`, `/=`, `<=`, `<`, `>=`, `>`) are frequently more convenient than `compare`, so I'd expect to see them used in code for `map`s or `filter`s.

You can [see `==` being used in guards on keys in `Data.Map` in fromAscListWithKey](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/src/Data-Map-Base.html). This specific function only calls out for the `Eq` class, but if the key is also an `Ord` instance, `Ord`'s `compare` will be used for other functions of the resulting `Map`, which is an assumption that `Eq`'s `==` is the same as `Ord`'s `compare` and testing for `EQ`.

As a library programmer, I wouldn't be surprised if any of the special purpose operators  outperformed `compare` for the specific purpose. After all, that's why they are part of the `Eq` and `Ord` classes instead of being defined as polymorphic for all `Eq` or `Ord` instances. I might make a point of using them even when `compare` is more convenient. If I did, I'd probably define something like:

```
compareOp :: (Ord a) => Ordering -> Bool -> a -> a -> Bool
compareOp EQ True  = (==)
compareOp EQ False = (/=)
compareOp LT True  = (<)
compareOp LT False = (>=)
compareOp GT True  = (>)
compareOp GT False = (<=)
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend Cirdec's answer, typeclass instances should only be made if the operation being defined is somehow *canonical*. If there is a reasonable `Eq` which doesn't extend to a reasonable `Ord`, then it's best practice to pick either the other `Eq` or to not define an `Ord`. It's easy enough to create a non-polymorphic function for the "other" equality.

A great example of this tension is the potential `Monoid` instance

```
instance Monoid Int where
  mzero = 0
  mappend = (+)
```

which contests with the other "obvious" `Monoid` instance

```
instance Monoid Int where
  mzero = 1
  mappend = (*)
```

In this case the chosen path was to instantiate neither because it's not clear that one is "canonical" over the other. This typically conforms best to a user's expectation and which prevent bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I've read through this and your original question, so I will address your general problem....

You want this-

```
Map BigThing OtherType
```

and this-

```
(==)::BigThing->BigThing->Bool
```

One of these cases has to be exact, the other case should ignore some of its data, for performance reasons.  (it was (==) that needed to be exact in the first question, but it looks like you might be addressing the reverse in this question....  Same answer either way).

For instance, you want the map to only store the result based on some label, like a

```
`name::BigThing->String`
```

but (==) should do a deep compare.  One way to do this would be to define incompatible `compare` and `(==)` functions.  However....

in this case, this is unnecessary.  Why not just instead use the map

```
Map String OtherThing
```

and do a lookup like this-

```
lookup (name obj) theMap
```

It is pretty rare to index directly on very large document data....

Comment: Just for the record, the older question was actually from someone else, not me (maybe my wording was a bit unclear) — but my situation is close enough that this answer works for me too, so thankyou in any case.