# Doing computation on tuples within a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given

```
data Allocation = 
    Alloc [(Var, Register)]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Allocation where
     Alloc a < Alloc b = .......
```

I want to see if one `Allocation` is better than another `Allocation` if `Alloc a` has fewer *distinct registers* than `Alloc b`.

I have a few methods/strategies that I think I can use, but not sure how to string them together.

**snd** can take the register out from the (Var, Register) tuple.
**nub** can remove the duplicates within a list
**length** for the length of the list
**intersect** to find the intersection between two lists

Attempt to extract the registers from `(Var, Register)` tuple for both `Alloc a` and `Alloc b`. Maybe find the intersection of the two lists, remove them from both lists, and compare the length of the remaining. If length `a` is greater than length `b`, `a` is the better one. Otherwise, it's `b`.

Am I overthinking this, or am I somehow on the right track?

Edit: Below is my attempt

```
helper :: Allocation -> [Register]
     helper (Alloc a) = nub (map snd a)

instance Ord Allocation where
    Alloc a < Alloc b = length (helper a - (helper a `intersect` helper b)) < length (helper b - (helper a `intersect` helper b))
```

So my helper works, but now the question is how do I delete a list from a list so that `a` will delete everything that is the intersection of `a` and `b` and `b` will do the same.

Comment: Have you looked at `Data.Set`?

Comment: As this is part of an assignment, I am limited to union, intersect, \\, and nub within Data.List. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I'd suggest faking `Data.Set` with `newtype Set a = Set [a]`, then `fromList :: [a] -> Set a`; `fromList = Set . nub`.  You can then build the common set manipulation functions based on that.  It's not very efficient but that's what you get when you're limited to `Data.List`.

Comment: You should probably take a stab at the code first, and show us what you have, then we can help.

Comment: added my code ! please take a look

Answer (score 1):

There’s a good chance I’m misunderstanding, but I think you might be overcomplicating it. Each allocation is a list of pairs of variables and registers, and the number of distinct registers used by an allocation is independent of the allocation it’s being compared with. As such, I’m not sure I understand why you’re doing an intersection.

If I’m understanding what you’re trying to do correctly, the most concise way to define the `Ord` instance would be like this:

```
instance Ord Allocation where
  compare = comparing (length . nub . map snd . assignments)
    where assignments (Allocation a) = a
```

Here, we, for each operand of `compare`:

- Extract the assignments from the allocation.
- Extract the registers from each assignment.
- Remove the duplicate registers.
- See how many registers are left.

Then we compare those two numbers, determining which is better that way. If you aren’t allowed to use `comparing`, you could just inline its relatively-short [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing).

Comment: I'd be very wary of writing an `Ord` instance where `compare a b = EQ` but `a == b = False`. The consequences of doing so are discussed in the following questions and their answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619303/haskell-do-standard-libraries-assume-eq-and-ord-are-compatible/20620124  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17114899/414413

Comment: @Cirdec: That’s a reasonable concern, but I’d be even more worried about having ``a `compare` b == LT && b `compare` a == LT``. I think the only way around both of these problems would be to define a fallback way to sort them in case the first check considers them equal—but without any such thing specified by the question, I’m not about to add that disambiguation logic.